# Skip files while merging git branches in both directions

Tags: git, git-merge, gitattributes

I have two branches in my git repo. There is a config file which should be different in two branches. I added `config merge=ours` to .gitattributes to preserve the config file when merging.
The config file does not get merged when merging from B branch to A branch. See the below graph

```
*---*---*---*--*(A)(HEAD) //config file in branch A remains
    \         /
     *---*---*(B)
```

However, when I merge from A branch to B, my config file also gets merge

```
*---*---*---*--*(A)
    \         /  \
     *---*---*----*(B)(HEAD) //config file in B gets merge with A
```

Can someone tell me what is the reason? And how I can preserve the file when merging from both directions?
Even though I found other discussions to preserve file when merge only one direction, I couldn't find a discussion about this particular scenario.

Comment: Bidirectional merging is not a good practice.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But this is an exceptional case which I have to take the changes from A

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A *merge driver* as defined in a `.gitattributes` file is used *only when all three input files differ*.

This means that setting `merge=ours` (and defining an `ours` merge driver) will often fail.  I recommend not bothering with this: just define your own process by which you'll handle these.

#### More detail

Remember first that `git merge` doesn't always do a real merge:

- `-s` / `--squash` directs it to not make a real merge at all, but it will still use the merge-as-a-verb action (and prohibits fast-forwarding).
- `--no-ff` will prohibit a fast-forward not-a-merge operation, forcing a real merge for this case.
- `--ff-only` will cause the command to fail (and not merge) if a fast-forward not-a-merge is not possible.

Keep these in mind when looking at the rest of this:

- We're considering only the resolve and recursive strategies here; octopus merges and `-s ours` are quite different.
- One of the input commits is always `HEAD`.  Another is the commit you name on the command line.  The `git merge` command will locate the merge base commit on its own; this is the third input commit.  If there is more than one merge base commit, `-s resolve` will pick one at random and `-s recursive` will first merge the merge bases—this is the inner recursive merge—and then make a new commit to use as the merge base for the outer merge.
- If the merge base commit is the `HEAD` commit, a fast-forward is possible.  If allowed, Git will not do a merge, and will instead just check out the other commit named on the command line, adjusting the current branch to point to that commit.
- If the merge base commit is the other commit, no merge is required: the current branch is up to date and nothing happens.

This leaves the real merge cases: there are three different commits involved.  Each of those commits has a full snapshot of however many files, and Git will:

- compare each file in the merge base to each file in `HEAD` to see what we changed;
- compare each file in the merge base to each file in the other commit to see what they changed; and
- combine these changes.

To combine these changes, Git will use a *low-level merge driver*.  This is the kind of driver you can define with a `merge=name` `.gitattributes` setting.  (Note: the recursive/resolve merge code will do its own high-level merging to handle newly-created files, deleted files, and renamed files, before reaching down to the low-level merge handler.  This high-level merge may produce a conflict, which will cause the merge to stop, regardless of whatever the low-level driver might do.)

This is where the problem comes in though: the high-level merge code, which handles any high-level conflicts, *doesn't bother to run the low-level merge code at all* if it can skip it.  This high-level code skips the low-level code whenever the raw hash IDs of the to-be-merged file(s) match across multiple commits.

That is, suppose *we* changed file `F` and *they did not*.  Then the hash of `F` in the merge base matches the hash of `F` in their commit, but the hash of `F` in *our* commit differs.  Git assumes that the correct action is to take our file: it never even *runs* the low-level merge driver.  With the default low-level driver, that's fine.  With an `ours` merge driver, that's still fine: Git took our `F`.

But suppose we *didn't* change `F` and they *did*.  Then the hash of `F` in the merge base matches the hash of `F` in our commit, but not the hash in theirs.  Git assumes that the correct action is to take their file.  It never runs the low-level driver, even if it is an `ours` merge driver.

If Git had a `.gitattributes` setting that forced it to run the low-level driver for each of these files, that would fix the problem.  But it does not.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. It makes sense why git doesn’t allow this.